# Showing geometry node fields in a custom UI is grayed out for collection

Tags: python, interface, geometry-nodes

I'm trying to create a custom UI that shows some geometry node modifier settings,
So far it's working for the most part but Collection and Objects fields are grayed out :

[image: some field are grayed out]

Is there a way to make them editable as the other fields ?
I've also tried a workaround by creating an EnumProperty that set collection inside the modifier , but I didn't managed to make it work as intended.

Any advices or something that would point me in the right direction would be very much apreciated !
Thanks !

Here is where I'm at with the script :

```
import bpy
from bpy.props import EnumProperty
from bpy.types import NodeSocketInterfaceCollection
            
class ModifierPanel(bpy.types.Panel):
    """Creates a Panel in the Object properties window"""
    bl_label = "Asset Properties"
    bl_idname = "OBJECT_PT_MOD"
    bl_space_type  = "VIEW_3D"
    bl_region_type = "UI"
    bl_category    = "EnvTools"

    @classmethod
    def poll(cls, context):
        return context.object is not None
        
    def draw(self, context):
        layout = self.layout
        obj    = context.object
        for mod in obj.modifiers :
            if mod.type != "NODES" : continue
            row = layout.row()
            grp = mod.node_group
            row = layout.row()
            for inp in grp.inputs :
                    if inp.type == "GEOMETRY" : continue
                
                    if inp.type == "COLLECTION" :
                        row.label(text=inp.name)
                        #row.prop(data = inp, property = "emb_col_enum", text = "")    
                        row.prop(data = mod, property = f'["{inp.identifier}"]', text = "")    
                        row = layout.row()
                        continue
                         
                    row.label(text=inp.name)
                    row.prop(data = mod, property = f'["{inp.identifier}"]', text = "",)
                    row = layout.row()

def col_enum_items(self, context) :
    cols = []
    t    = 0
    for c in bpy.data.collections :
        cols.append( (c.name, c.name, c.name, t) )
        #cols.append( (c.name, c.name, c.name) )
        t += 1
    
    return (cols)

def col_enum_get(self) :

    # work but misses default
    #return(self["emb_col_enum"])

    # locked 
    mod = socket_get_modifier(self)
    col = mod[self.identifier].name
    t = 0
    for c in bpy.data.collections :
        if c.name == col : return(t)
        t += 1
    return(0)

    
def col_enum_set(self, value) :
    self["emb_col_enum"]=value
    #mod =  socket_get_modifier(self)
    #mod[self.identifier] = bpy.data.collections[self.emb_col_enum]
        
    
def socket_get_modifier(socket) :
    mod = None
    mod_name = socket.id_data.name
    for md in bpy.context.active_object.modifiers :
        if md.node_group.name == mod_name : mod = md
    return(mod)

def col_enum_update(self, context) :
    mod =  socket_get_modifier(self)
    mod[self.identifier] = bpy.data.collections[self.emb_col_enum]

    
def register():
    bpy.utils.register_class(ModifierPanel)

    NodeSocketInterfaceCollection.emb_col_enum = EnumProperty(
    name="Collection",                    
    items=col_enum_items,     
    #get=col_enum_get,     
    #set=col_enum_set,
    update = col_enum_update)



def unregister():
    bpy.utils.unregister_class(ModifierPanel)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    register()
    print("reg")
```

Comment: Hello, not an answer but I think you could get a much more readable code if you used the [next](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#next) and/or [enumerate](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#enumerate) builtin functions instead of your for loops

Comment: try 'template_node_view()', learn more https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.types.UILayout.html?highlight=ui#bpy.types.UILayout.template_node_link

Comment: Gorgious thanks for the tips ! @Karan thanks too ! I've looked into that and it wasn't exactly what I was looking for ! this access the node tree, not the instance of that node ( on the modifier pannel)

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if you find an answer or not but you can make dictionary of input types and then use it with `prop_search` instead of `prop` for the non-numeric based inputs.